# AggregateResult query does not return any result using Apex and Salesforce LWC

Tags: apex, javascript, lightning-web-components, html

I am trying to get both starting and ending calendar years of standard **Period** object in Salesforce. The idea is that fiscal year starts in February of the current year and ends in January next year (e.g. Feb2020-January2021). Both start and end dates can be easily determined by filtering Period object where Type = 'Year'.

I have a Fiscal Year picklist value on LWC page (FY2019, FY2020, FY2021), which represents the starting year. To match the returned data type of `CALENDAR_YEAR(StartDate)` from the query, I omitted first two characters from the selected picklist value, then converted the returned string into Integer.

Now challenge I am encountering is that result does not return anything. I made sure that there are rows returned in Salesforce Workbench.

Following is the result I am getting in my browser's developer console for the javascript:

[image]

Following are the current codes I have:

**periodLWC.html**

```
<template> 
    
    <lightning-combobox
        class="slds-m-bottom_small slds-m-left_small"
        name="fiscalYear"
        label="Fiscal Year"
        value={yearValue}
        placeholder="--None--"
        options={yearOptions}
        onchange={findOrgFYData}>
    </lightning-combobox>  
       
</template>
```

**periodLWC.js**

```
import { LightningElement, track} from 'lwc';


import getFYOrgDataFromApex from '@salesforce/apex/PeriodController.getFYOrgData'; 


export default class periodLWC extends LightningElement {

  
    @track periodData = [];

    @track error;
   
    @track yearValue = '--None--';

    @track yearOptions = [
        {value: 'FY2019', label: 'FY2019'},
        {value: 'FY2020', label: 'FY2020'},
        {value: 'FY2021', label: 'FY2021'}
    ];

    
    findOrgFYData(event) {
        const orgYear = event.target.value;

        var orgStartFY = orgYear.substring(2);

        console.log('Trimmed fiscal year value is===>' + orgStartFY);

        var orgStartFYInt = parseInt(orgStartFY, 10);

        console.log('Converted integer is===>' + orgStartFYInt);

        if(orgStartFYInt) {
           
            getFYOrgDataFromApex({orgStartFYInt})
            .then(result => {
                if(result) {
                    console.log('Returned results===>' + result);        
                }
                
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.error = error;
            })    
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

**PeriodController.cls**

```
public class PeriodController{

       @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)

       public static List<Integer> getFYOrgData(Integer orgYear) {

              List<Integer> intList = new List<Integer>();
              List<AggregateResult> aggList = new List<AggregateResult>();

              aggList = [SELECT CALENDAR_YEAR(EndDate) endYear,Id,CALENDAR_YEAR(StartDate) startYear,Type FROM Period 
                     WHERE Type = 'Year' AND CALENDAR_YEAR(StartDate) =: orgYear
                     GROUP BY Id, Type, CALENDAR_YEAR(EndDate), CALENDAR_YEAR(StartDate)  ];
              
              if(aggList.size() > 0) {

                     for(AggregateResult agg : aggList) {
                            
                            Date fyStartYear = (Date) agg.get('startYear');
                            Date fyEndYear = (Date) agg.get('endYear');

                            Integer intFyStartYear = fyStartYear.year();
                            Integer intFyEndYear = fyEndYear.year();

                            intList.add(intFyStartYear);
                            intList.add(intFyEndYear);              
                     }
                     
              }

              return intList;  
                           
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem 1: Parameter Name Mismatch

Your Apex has the signature:

```
   public static List<Integer> getFYOrgData(Integer orgYear) {
```

But you call it with:

```
   getFYOrgDataFromApex({orgStartFYInt})
```

The names must match, and are case sensitive.

## Problem 2: Invalid Runtime Conversion

The CALENDAR_YEAR function (and others like it, such as DAY_ONLY) return an Integer value, not a full date. Your Apex needs to change as follows:

```
  for (AggregateResult agg : aggList) {
    Integer intFyStartYear = (Integer) agg.get('startYear');
    Integer intFyEndYear = (Integer) agg.get('endYear');

    intList.add(intFyStartYear);
    intList.add(intFyEndYear);
  }
```

P.S. `if (aggList.size() > 0)` is not necessary. It is perfectly legal to iterate over an empty list.

Comment: I totally missed out those two important things. Results are now returned perfectly upon applying your suggestions. Thanks for your immediate response and help :)